# Sharing Typescript classes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two classes written in typescript that I want to be able to make available to all projects. These are not components. Declarations look like this:

First class:

```
export class CheckboxFilter {} // This has no dependencies
```

Second class:

```
import {CookieService} from 'angular2-cookie/core';
import {CookieOptionsArgs} from 'angular2-cookie/core';
import {CheckboxFilter} from './CheckboxFilter';
export class CheckboxManager {}
```

What is the simplest way to package these so they can be included in other projects

Comment: Did you try github or NPM?

Comment: "Simple" is in the eye of the beholder... It's unclear what part you're finding complicated that you want to make simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just those two classes, cut and paste or file share is probably the easiest way.

The next option is an npm package.  I have had a lot of success using this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular2-library) to create Angular npm packages.  You can create the package and then deploy it to a private npm or just copy it to a file share.  Then run an npm install  on any project that will use it.